# why is the javascript date month index 0-based

Tags: javascript, date

I have read numerous explanation attempts why this was created like this back in the day (with both year and day index are **not** being 0-based). None of these explanations really made sense.

What is even more surprising to me: even in the latest ECMAScript 2018 draft, this issue still exists.
[see dates in ECMAScript 2018](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-objects%22dates%20in%20ECMAScript%202018%22)

Javascript might have just taken this from Java long time ago but I don't see why it is not being changed unless there actually **is** a proper reason for it.

Thanks & regards,
Marcel

Comment: Q: Did you celebrate the new millenium Jan 1, 2000 ... or Jan 1, 2001?

Comment: `why it is not being changed unless there actually is a proper reason for it.` dude just assumes changing this "little" detail is like opening up the file in an editor, locate the line, backspace, backspace, save, done. Not easy bud

Comment: Paraphrased from the duplicate: _TL;DR: Because months and weekdays have names and days of the month do not._

Comment: @paulsm4: I went with both. :-) Hey...party!

Comment: Days of the week are also zero indexed (Sunday = 0) as are years. So zero indexing months makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

> why is the javascript date month index 0-based

It's not surprising. The day of the week is also 0-based. In both cases, it's common to want to look up symbolic versions of them in arrays (e.g., `["January", "February", ...]`, `["Sunday", "Monday", ...]`). Arrays are 0-based. JavaScript is by far not the only language/runtime that uses 0-based values for this.

> What is even more surprising to me: even in the latest ECMAScript 2018 draft, this issue still exists.

It would be ***much*** more surprising if they changed this 22 years after the fact, blowing up millions of scripts, esp. as it's perfectly rational the way it is. They could *add* a new accessor that does the `+1` for you, but...yeah, I wouldn't hold my breath. :-)

The only reason for 1-based versions of these is formatting. Formatting isn't handled by JavaScript at all. There *is* some formatting in ECMA-402: [ECMAScript® 2016 Internationalization API Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html), in the form of [`DateTimeFormat`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-402/3.0/index.html#datetimeformat-objects).

Comment: Since the ancestors are Java and C before it and ASM before that, the 22 years is not enough ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: :-)