# Getting wrong date for Javascript Date() function

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I am trying to use the "new Date()" function but my dates are not coming out correctly.

This date & time is correct if I use:

```
new Date(); //outputs Wed Jul 05 2017 13:16:31 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

When I try to change the date, it comes out incorrect:

```
new Date(2017,07,03,12,01,36); //outputs Thu Aug 03 2017 12:01:36 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

I'm not sure why it says "Aug" when it should be "Jul".

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828883/why-is-the-javascript-date-month-index-0-based

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate, I didn't see the other questions when searching my issue. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> month is 0-based

[Date - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

```
new Date(2017,06,03,12,01,36) // Mon Jul 03 2017 12:01:36 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Similar questions

- [javascript is creating date wrong month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254333/javascript-is-creating-date-wrong-month)
- [why is the javascript date month index 0-based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828883/why-is-the-javascript-date-month-index-0-based)
- [Why does the month argument range from 0 to 11 in JavaScript's Date constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552483/why-does-the-month-argument-range-from-0-to-11-in-javascripts-date-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

It is because months start from zero. So, if you want July, you have to set month to 06

Answer (score 0):

The month parameter starts at 0, so if you want to put July you must write 6 instead of 7.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date